# Best practice to parse/manage a huge JSON file (~19MB) on Android

Tags: android, json, file, parsing, gson

I have a huge JSON file to parse in my Android app.
I suppose it is too big to parse it, probably the memory won't be enough. I usually parse just small file with GSON lib.

Is there a best practice for that? Or, do you suggest something to work it out?

Any suggestions is well appreciated.

Comment: wait, what! 19MB...? really??? damnnnn :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're definitely going to need to use a streaming parser like JsonReader. It's available both in Gson ([link](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html)) and in Android 3.0+ ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)). You should use `skipValue()` aggressively since that avoids allocating objects that you aren't going to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), make sure you use the streaming API instead of the databind API, then remember to use `skipChildren()` as agressively as possible. An example of using the streaming API is available [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/).

Answer (score 0):

For Parsing GSON is good where by making POJO you can parse JSON object to directly Java Object. and for the lengthy file you must do this in a separate thread i.e other than UI Thread For this You can Use AsyncTask a Utility for Managing thread. below is complete refrence to it

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html